# Loader inside a table <td>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put loader inside a table but it is not working. The issue is when I am putting div inside a td, the tabular format is not working.

When I inspected the elements the div was outside of the table.

```css
.loader {
  background: #000;
  background: radial-gradient(#222, #000);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.loader-inner {
  height: 60px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader-line-wrap {
  animation: spin 2000ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader-line {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -50ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -100ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -150ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -200ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -250ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(0, 80%, 60%);
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  top: 7px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(60, 80%, 60%);
  height: 76px;
  width: 76px;
  top: 14px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(120, 80%, 60%);
  height: 62px;
  width: 62px;
  top: 21px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(180, 80%, 60%);
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  top: 28px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(240, 80%, 60%);
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  top: 35px;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0%, 15% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="preloader" class="loader">
        <div class="loader-inner">
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is working at my side check https://jsfiddle.net/dbwog4zt/  . please post a jsfiddle which shows your issue.

Comment: @geeksal I believe the OP wants the loading to be contained within the `<td>` which won't happen since they're using fixed positioning.

Comment: The same output I am also getting . What exactly I want is the loader needs to be inside the table. I just commented the background and added border for a table. look into this https://jsfiddle.net/dbwog4zt/

Comment: @VenkateshVoona you forget to update fiddle. Just click the save button and copy and paste the updated url.

Comment: Sorry, here is the one https://jsfiddle.net/VenkyVoona/x9rcabzq/

Comment: @geeksal When I change fixed position , the background color is disapearing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to contain the loading graphic within the `<td>` then you should not use fixed positioning.

Here is one solution. Remove the fixed positioning and related properties. Set positioning to relative along with a height and width for `.loader`.

```css
.loader {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  background: radial-gradient(#222, #000);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.loader-inner {}
.loader-line-wrap {
  animation: spin 2000ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader-line {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -50ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -100ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -150ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -200ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -250ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(0, 80%, 60%);
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  top: 7px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(60, 80%, 60%);
  height: 76px;
  width: 76px;
  top: 14px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(120, 80%, 60%);
  height: 62px;
  width: 62px;
  top: 21px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(180, 80%, 60%);
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  top: 28px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(240, 80%, 60%);
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  top: 35px;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0%, 15% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="preloader" class="loader">
        <div class="loader-inner">
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you hungerstar and geeksal for the quick response. Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

Add an id or class to the loader's parent `td` and set its position to `relative`. Make the loader's position `absolute`.

```css
#loaderContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader {
  background: #000;
  background: radial-gradient(#222, #000);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.loader-inner {
  height: 60px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader-line-wrap {
  animation: spin 2000ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader-line {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -50ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -100ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -150ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -200ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -250ms;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(0, 80%, 60%);
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  top: 7px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(60, 80%, 60%);
  height: 76px;
  width: 76px;
  top: 14px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(120, 80%, 60%);
  height: 62px;
  width: 62px;
  top: 21px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(180, 80%, 60%);
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  top: 28px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) .loader-line {
  border-color: hsl(240, 80%, 60%);
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  top: 35px;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0%, 15% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="loaderContainer">
      <div id="preloader" class="loader">
        <div class="loader-inner">
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="loader-line-wrap">
            <div class="loader-line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @hungester - Can u plz let me know, why you are removed jsfiddle link from my answer. Any specific reason ?

Comment: For the same reasons StackOverflow asks people to post Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples instead of linking to a website or to code offsite. By keeping everything contained on SO future visitors don't have to worry about external resources not being available in the future. Your code now runs in a snippet exclusively on StackOverflow. Your example is very simple and within the capabilities of a SO Code Snippet. Though there are times where JSFiddle/CodePen is more capable than a SO Code Snippet and would be used instead.